# Failed to start up WiredTiger under any compatibility version. This may be due to an unsupported upgrade or downgrade

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, ubuntu-20.04

Getting this error on Ubuntu 20.04.

I had origianlly installed the default version 3.0.6 on ubuntu.

I have purged it and installed 5.0.9. But now I get this error in logs and mongod won't start.

`"Failed to start up WiredTiger under any compatibility version. This may be due to an unsupported upgrade or downgrade."`

Comment: Stop the service, delete data directory, start the service

Comment: I need to keep the data. How would I do that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's a massive gap between versions. You need to upgrade all versions in-between one at a time: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/release-notes/5.0-upgrade-standalone/#upgrade-version-path:

> To upgrade an existing MongoDB deployment to 5.0, you must be running a 4.4-series release.
>
> To upgrade from a version earlier than the 4.4-series, you must successively upgrade major releases until you have upgraded to 4.4-series. For example, if you are running a 4.2-series, you must upgrade first to 4.4 before you can upgrade to 5.0.

Or you can export data from 3.0.6 , start 5.0.9 with **empty** data directory (Storage.dbPath option in config), import data to 5.0.9

Comment: Ok, thanks. This app isn't live yet so we just wiped the `/var/lib/mongodb/*` directory and it works now.

Comment: @chovy, worked for me as well for Mongo-5.0. Thanks

Comment: Always do "mongodump" before upgrade. I cleaned /var/lib/mongodb/* directory, started mongod service and restored data from dump. Works like a charm!

Comment: Additionally, you can get another error like "Failed to unlink socket file" that it will be resolved with rm -rf /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock

Comment: Additionally I had to wipe `rm -rf /data/db/*`