# docker-compose up -d, fail start

Tags: docker, docker-compose, nestjs

I am new to docker and I have the problem that when I start the command "docker-compose up -d" the first time it creates the local folder fine and raises the database. The problem arises when I try to use the command again. The in docker desktop does not raise the database with the local.

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  db:
    image: mongo:5.0.0
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    environment:
      MONGODB_DATABASE: nest-craft
    volumes:
      - ./mongo:/data/db
```

So I have to delete my local database folder so I can start docker-compose again, but that's when I lose all my data.

I see that on my docker desktop the volume reboots, without being able to start.

Console errors:

```
craft-db-1  | {"t":{"$date":"2023-05-06T17:02:37.051+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23285,   "ctx":"-","msg":"Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'"}
craft-db-1  | {"t":{"$date":"2023-05-06T17:02:37.052+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4915701, "ctx":"-","msg":"Initialized wire specification","attr":{"spec":{"incomingExternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"incomingInternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"outgoing":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"isInternalClient":true}}}
craft-db-1  | {"t":{"$date":"2023-05-06T17:02:37.053+00:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22601,   "ctx":"main","msg":"No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup"}
craft-db-1  | {"t":{"$date":"2023-05-06T17:02:37.053+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4648601, "ctx":"main","msg":"Implicit TCP FastOpen unavailable. If TCP FastOpen is required, set tcpFastOpenServer, tcpFastOpenClient, and tcpFastOpenQueueSize."}
craft-db-1  | {"t":{"$date":"2023-05-06T17:02:37.054+00:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22601,   "ctx":"main","msg":"No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup"}
craft-db-1  | {"t":{"$date":"2023-05-06T17:02:37.054+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"main","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"TenantMigrationDonorService","ns":"config.tenantMigrationDonors"}}
craft-db-1  | {"t":{"$date":"2023-05-06T17:02:37.054+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"main","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"TenantMigrationRecipientService","ns":"config.tenantMigrationRecipients"}}
craft-db-1  | {"t":{"$date":"2023-05-06T17:02:37.055+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4615611, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"MongoDB starting","attr":{"pid":1,"port":27017,"dbPath":"/data/db","architecture":"64-bit","host":"df3de195f4af"}}
craft-db-1  | {"t":{"$date":"2023-05-06T17:02:37.055+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23403,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Build Info","attr":{"buildInfo":{"version":"5.0.0","gitVersion":"1184f004a99660de6f5e745573419bda8a28c0e9","openSSLVersion":"OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020","modules":[],"allocator":"tcmalloc","environment":{"distmod":"ubuntu2004","distarch":"x86_64","target_arch":"x86_64"}}}}
craft-db-1  | {"t":{"$date":"2023-05-06T17:02:37.055+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":51765,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Operating System","attr":{"os":{"name":"Ubuntu","version":"20.04"}}}
craft-db-1  | {"t":{"$date":"2023-05-06T17:02:37.055+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":21951,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Options set by command line","attr":{"options":{"net":{"bindIp":"*"}}}}
craft-db-1  | {"t":{"$date":"2023-05-06T17:02:37.059+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22270,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Storage engine to use detected by data files","attr":{"dbpath":"/data/db","storageEngine":"wiredTiger"}}
craft-db-1  | {"t":{"$date":"2023-05-06T17:02:37.061+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22315,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Opening WiredTiger","attr":{"config":"create,cache_size=480M,session_max=33000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),builtin_extension_config=(zstd=(compression_level=6)),file_manager=(close_idle_time=600,close_scan_interval=10,close_handle_minimum=250),statistics_log=(wait=0),verbose=[recovery_progress,checkpoint_progress,compact_progress],"}}
craft-db-1  | {"t":{"$date":"2023-05-06T17:02:37.248+00:00"},"s":"E",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22435,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger error","attr":{"error":1,"message":"[1683392557:248748][1:0x7fc07daa3c80], file:WiredTiger.wt, connection: __posix_open_file, 805: /data/db/WiredTiger.wt: handle-open: open: Operation not permitted"}}
craft-db-1  | {"t":{"$date":"2023-05-06T17:02:37.269+00:00"},"s":"E",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22435,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger error","attr":{"error":1,"message":"[1683392557:269467][1:0x7fc07daa3c80], file:WiredTiger.wt, connection: __posix_open_file, 805: /data/db/WiredTiger.wt: handle-open: open: Operation not permitted"}}
craft-db-1  | {"t":{"$date":"2023-05-06T17:02:37.291+00:00"},"s":"E",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22435,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger error","attr":{"error":1,"message":"[1683392557:291042][1:0x7fc07daa3c80], file:WiredTiger.wt, connection: __posix_open_file, 805: /data/db/WiredTiger.wt: handle-open: open: Operation not permitted"}}
craft-db-1  | {"t":{"$date":"2023-05-06T17:02:37.293+00:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22347,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Failed to start up WiredTiger under any compatibility version. This may be due to an unsupported upgrade or downgrade."}
craft-db-1  | {"t":{"$date":"2023-05-06T17:02:37.294+00:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":28595,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Terminating.","attr":{"reason":"1: Operation not permitted"}}
craft-db-1  | {"t":{"$date":"2023-05-06T17:02:37.294+00:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"-",        "id":23091,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Fatal assertion","attr":{"msgid":28595,"file":"src/mongo/db/storage/wiredtiger/wiredtiger_kv_engine.cpp","line":690}}
craft-db-1  | {"t":{"$date":"2023-05-06T17:02:37.294+00:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"-",        "id":23092,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"\n\n***aborting after fassert() failure\n\n"}ten","msg":"\n\n***aborting after fassert() failure\n\n"}
```

Comment: Does the container produce any error logs? If so: please [edit] the post and add the (relevant) logs.

Comment: If you're using the command from the command line, remove the `-d` as it will then probably show some errors on the command line output

Comment: Yes, I just edited the post with the console errors, thanks @Turing85

Comment: It looks like a known, old issue: https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/138. Try using `mongo:5.0` (or 5.0.17 if you want to specify the full version) instead of `mongo:5.0.0` to get a newer version where it might be fixed.

Comment: @HansKilian I changed the version to 5 and 5.0
But the problem continues, I read the link and apparently it is because I use windows 10 Pro. Too bad, but it was tried. thank you

Comment: [This dba post might be related/a duplicate](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/186478/mongodb-refuse-to-start-operation-not-permitted).

Comment: @HansKilian I found the solution, I had to install this package "WSL2 Linux kernel update package for x64 machines"
From here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-manual#step-4---download-the-linux-kernel-update-package
Installing it fixed the error and it now keeps the local mongo data for me :D

Comment: i think your answer in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73156404/12599279), try it.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps, hope it, fix the issue.

It will stop your container:

```
docker-compose down
```

it will remove the container volume:

```
docker-compose rm -f
```

It will create a new DB:

```
docker-compose up -d
```